# Paginas no encontradas Django

Tags: django, django-urls

Tengo un proyecto a medio camino y estuve agregando unas paginas nuevas, pero al tratar de acceder me dice lo siguiente:

```
Using the URLconf defined in authtest.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$ [name='home']
^resolutividad/ [name='resolutividad']
^reincidencias/ [name='reincidencias']
^malescalado/ [name='malescalado']
^noprocede/ [name='noprocede']
^escalamiento/ [name='escalamiento']
^subestado201701/ [name='subestado201701']
^subestado201702/ [name='subestado201702']
^subestado201703/ [name='subestado201703']
^subestado201704/ [name='subestado201704']
^subestado201705/ [name='subestado201705']
^subestado201706/ [name='subestado201706']
^subestado201707/ [name='subestado201707']
^subestado201708/ [name='subestado201708']
^subestado201709/ [name='subestado201709']
^subestado201710/ [name='subestado201710']
^login/$ [name='login']
^logout/$
The current path, subestados201701, didn't match any of these.
```

Las paginas llamadas "subestado" son las del problema.

Urls.py:

```
#!python
# log/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from escaladas.views import tabla
import escaladas
import subestadosdecierre.enero as se
import subestadosdecierre.febrero as sf
import subestadosdecierre.marzo as sm
import subestadosdecierre.abril as sa
import subestadosdecierre.mayo as sma
import subestadosdecierre.junio as sj
import subestadosdecierre.julio as sju
import subestadosdecierre.agosto as sag
import subestadosdecierre.septiembre as ss
import subestadosdecierre.octubre as so
# We are adding a URL called /home
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^resolutividad/', views.resolutividad, name='resolutividad'),
    url(r'^reincidencias/', views.reincidencias, name='reincidencias'),
    url(r'^malescalado/', views.malescalado, name='malescalado'),
    url(r'^noprocede/', views.noprocede, name='noprocede'),
    url(r'^escalamiento/', views.escalamiento, name='escalamiento'),
    url(r'^subestado201701/',se.tabla, name='subestado201701'),
    url(r'^subestado201702/',sf.tabla, name='subestado201702'),
    url(r'^subestado201703/',sm.tabla, name='subestado201703'),
    url(r'^subestado201704/',sa.tabla, name='subestado201704'),
    url(r'^subestado201705/',sma.tabla, name='subestado201705'),
    url(r'^subestado201706/',sj.tabla, name='subestado201706'),
    url(r'^subestado201707/',sju.tabla, name='subestado201707'),
    url(r'^subestado201708/',sag.tabla, name='subestado201708'),
    url(r'^subestado201709/',ss.tabla, name='subestado201709'),
    url(r'^subestado201710/',so.tabla, name='subestado201710'),
```

enero.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as ps
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et


def tabla(request):
    lista = ['Sub Estado','Grupo Resolutor ']
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:alphabeta@localhost:5432/escaladas')
    t='resueltas 01/2017'
    sqltable = ps.read_sql_table(t,engine,columns=lista)
    sqltable.columns = sqltable.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
    sqltable.columns = sqltable.columns.str.replace('*', '')
    sqltable.columns = sqltable.columns.str.replace('+', '')
    sqltable.columns = sqltable.columns.str.replace('?', '')
    sqltable.columns = sqltable.columns.str.replace('-', '')
    sqltable.columns = sqltable.columns.str.replace('/', '_')
    sqltable.columns = sqltable.columns.str.replace('.', '')
    print(sqltable.info(memory_usage='deep'))

    sqltable2 = sqltable.groupby([ 'Grupo_Resolutor_', 'Sub_Estado']).size().to_frame()
    table = et.fromstring(sqltable2.to_html(classes= ["table-bordered", "table-striped", "table-hover"]))
    table222 = et.fromstring(sqltable.to_html(classes= ["table-bordered", "table-striped", "table-hover"]))
    table.set('id', 'dataTables-example')
    table.set('cellspacing', '0')

    et.tostring(table)
    return render(request,'subestados201701.html',{'tabla':sqltable2})
"""["table-bordered", "table-striped", "table-hover"]"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo al error:

```
The current path, subestados201701, didn't match any of these.
```

Estás intentando ingresar a la URL `subestados201701` (en plural) cuando la definición de tus URLs las has hecho en singular:

```
url(r'^subestado201701/',se.tabla, name='subestado201701'),
```

Comment: Pues facepalm !! tienes toda la razon.

Comment: @Anthony errar es humano ;-)